# Calling a Jersey API from a remote location

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, jersey, http-post

This might be a very trivial questions, but I couldn't find any Specific question on SO.

I have developed an RESTful API using Jersey. I tested this on the localhost and it works fine. Now I thew it onto the RPi and tested it locally it works fine.

When I try to access this same API from my mac it gives me an error of could not connect to the webservice.

During my local test I used the URL:

http://localhost:8080/healthyhome/**webresource/myresources**

Now to access the same service I use Yaler Tunnel to take of my firewall and make a tunnel through it.

I call the service on PORT:8080 same as tomcat. When I'm listen to the port it shows me the incoming POST request with form-data that I passed.

But when I run the tomcat it does not.

I send request to the URL:

http://********.try.yaler.net/**webresource/myresources**

What do you think I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Try http://********.try.yaler.net/healthyhome/webresource/myresources (i.e. including the healthyhome part). Kind regards, Thomas